# Using SharedResourceDictionary in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, resourcedictionary

Christian Moser [provides](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html) a SharedResourceDictionary for WPF to reuse and initialize resources only once.

I´ve tried to use his implementation in my Silverlight 4 application, but i´m getting COMExceptions in Visual Studio or a message that the element is already a child of an other element.

Has anyone successfully used SharedResourceDictionary in a Silverlight application or is there a similar way to reuse ResourceDictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look promising for using it in Silverlight, I think [this bug on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/518454/element-is-already-the-child-of-another-element-when-using-a-resource-dictionary-twice) relates exactly to the problem, and that was last updated 2 years ago...